# Idempotent matrix with linear transformation

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I am struggling on the properties of the idempotent matrix, namely for any $%
n\times n$ matrix $A,$ $A^{2}=A.$ The projection matrix defined by $%
M=I_{n}-A\left( A^{T}A\right) ^{-1}A^{T}$ is an idempotent matrix. The
question is, for any given $n\times m$ ($n>m$) matrix $B,$ do we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
M &=&I_{n}-A\left( A^{T}A\right) ^{-1}A^{T} \\
&=&I_{n}-AB\left( B^{T}A^{T}AB\right) ^{-1}B^{T}A^{T},
\end{eqnarray*}
since $AB$ is basically the linear transformation of matrix $A.$ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, your projection matrix makes sense if $rank\, A =k < n$. Otherwise, $M=0$. If so, $M$ maps to the $n-k$-dimensional linear space spanned by the vectors $c_i$, orthogonal to the columns of $A$.

Now, when you consider $\bar M =I_{n}-AB\left( B^{T}A^{T}AB\right)^{-1}B^{T}A^{T}$, this operator maps to the linear subspace orthogonal to the column space of $AB$. Here, you can have different options depending on the rank of $AB$.

Let, for instance, $rank\, AB = rank\, A$. In this case, the column space of $AB$ is the same as the column space of $A$ and $M=\bar M$. But this will not be the case if $rank\, AB < rank\, A$.